# How to query solr server from php in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, search

How do you query solr server from php in Drupal 8?

I have installed search_api, search_api_solr and search_api_attachments.  Also have Solr v.8.4.0 installed.

I installed php SolrClient for Centos 7 following this guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959330/fatal-error-class-solrclient-not-found
, but I still get "*Class 'SolrClient' not found*" every time I run

```
new SolrClient($options);
```

I have located documentation on querying Solr from php in Drupal 7 (apachesolr_get_solr()) but nothing in Drupal 8.

Comment: You can either do it through the SearchAPI services or use Solarium client directly. I recommend the first way if you are not a programmer or very familiar with Solr querying. https://gist.github.com/kevinquillen/cad07541347385744b161a26690ab75d Is one example.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get SolrClient working and that method appears to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problems with SolrClient install: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052999/php-warning-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules-solr-so-und%C2%A0

This is how I can now query the solr server from php (right out of php SolrClient manual):

```
$options = array
(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port'     => '8983',
    'path'     => 'solr/sbn01'
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery('*file/10*');

$query->setStart(0);

$query->setRows(50);

$query->addField('id');
$query->addField('its_fid');
$query->addField('ss_uri');

$query_response = $client->query($query);

$response = $query_response->getResponse();

print_r($response);
```

Comment: But what is "SolrClient"? SearchAPI Solr has a dependency on Solarium which is a client itself that the module builds on top of. All that's needed is to include which of the two you want to use in your code and adhere to their API.

Comment: PHP:SolrClient::query: https://www.php.net/manual/en/solrclient.query.php

Can you point me to any documentation on how to use SearchAPISolr services?   I looked at example here:  https://gist.github.com/kevinquillen/cad07541347385744b161a26690ab75d But can't figure it out.